# NanoPi / DietPi - Enable USB serial and USB mass storage

Tags: linux, usb, usb-flash-drive

I got a NanoPi NEO LTS running latest version of [DietPi](https://dietpi.com/docs/hardware/#nanopi-series-friendlyelec). The board has two USB ports (One micro and a 2.0) and an Ethernet port.

What I'd like to do:

- Connect Ethernet to a different network than my computer (Then I can't use it to get a SSH connection).
- Connect micro-USB to my computer to get a Serial connection to the NanoPi.
- Connect the USB 2.0 port to a computer to act as a USB mass storage (to drop files to the NanoPi).

To use the micro-USB as a Serial port, I've created the following service `/etc/systemd/system/u-serial.service`:

```
[Unit]
Description=Load u_serial kernel module

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/modprobe u_serial

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

To use the USB 2.0 as an USB storage gadget, I have created a new service `/etc/systemd/system/gadget-storage.service` and a new directory `/usb_storage`:

```
[Unit]
Description=USB gadget storage service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/sbin/modprobe usb_f_mass_storage file=/usb_storage stall=0 removable=1 idVendor=0x0781 idProduct=0x5567 iManufacturer="NanoPi" iProduct="NanoPi Drive" iSerialNumber="1234567890"iProduct="$IPRODUCT" iSerialNumber="$ISERIALNUMBER"

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

So far, neither the USB Serial nor the USB gadget work.
How could I make it run that way ?

`u-serial` and `usb_f_mass_storage` were found using `lsmod`.
If I was able to use `g_acm_ms` (Mass storage + Serial) on micro-USB port, if would be even better !

**EDIT:**

I've also tried with Armbian. Adding the following lines to `/boot/armbianEnv.txt` makes the Serial connection available at `/dev/tty.usbmodem14301`.

```
echo "dtoverlay=dwc2" >> /boot/armbianEnv.txt
echo "modules-load=dwc2,g_acm_ms" >> /boot/armbianEnv.txt
echo "g_acm_ms.file=/mnt/usb_storage" >> /boot/armbianEnv.txt
echo "g_acm_ms.stall=0" >> /boot/armbianEnv.txt

# Enable Serial forward service
sudo systemctl enable getty@ttyGS0.service
```

The USB mass storage is still not detected. Plus, how to change the name of the TTY device ?

Comment: "*The board has two USB ports (One micro and a 2.0)*" -- That's an inaccurate and ambiguous statement. Presumably the "*micro*" connector is a B receptacle that supports OTG (i.e. either host or gadget mode). The "*2.0*" presumably is a type A receptacle that only supports USB host mode. "*Connect micro-USB to my computer to get a Serial connection*" -- Feasible if this USB port operates in gadget mode and uses CDC ACM.  "*Connect the USB 2.0 port to a computer to act as a USB mass storage*" -- Not feasible since a USB host cannot connect to another USB host.